# Kendo data-bind with custom objects in <select> element

Tags: data-binding, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm just starting with kendo UI and right away got stuck with a rather simple problem.
So I have

- first select element which consists of array of 'User' objects.
- regular input with username
- second select containing user roles

Code I have so far:

HTML markup:

```
<form id="change-user">
   <select data-text-field="username" data-bind="source: userList, value: selectedUser">
   </select>
   <label>Username: <input data-bind="value: selectedUser.username"></label>
   <label>Role: 
       <select data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id" data-bind="source: userRoles, value: selectedUser.role"></select>
   </label>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var model = kendo.observable({
        userList: [
            {
                id: 1,
                username: 'user1',
                role: 1
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                username: 'user2',
                role: 2
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                username: 'user3',
                role: 3
            }
        ],
        selectedUser: null,
        userRoles: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Admin'
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'User'
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Moderator'
            }
        ]
    });

    kendo.bind($('form#change-user'), model);
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It seems that property 'selectedUser' gets string value 'user1', 'user2' and so on instead of becoming javascript object.

I know solution to my problem is probably really simple, but I couldn't figure it out - kendo documentation is really massive and I'm not sure which keywords I should google.

Thank you.

Comment: So, you want the value of the first `<select/>` to be the User object itself and not its `username` property?

Comment: This isn't what you want? [http://jsfiddle.net/PytHq/](http://jsfiddle.net/PytHq/)

Comment: @Brett Yes, I want value for the first select to be 'User' object, so in observable selectedUser could become object instead of string so that second checkbox could modify 'User' object. The code you provided doesn't seem to be solving this problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot bind and object to the value of a dropdownlist using declarative syntax on the HTML elements. Kendo expects an object property to be bound which is of a value data type, like string or number. You can however get the behavior you seek by declaring the first dropdownlist in javascript and hooking into its change or select events to bind the selected user to your observable model. Then, the rest of the controls behave the way you expect.

Here's an example of how you should define the first dropdownlist, and here's a link to a working example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PytHq/3/.

```
$('#users').kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: userList,
    dataTextField: 'username',
    dataValueField: 'id',
    change: function () {
        model.set('selectedUser', $('#users').data('kendoDropDownList').dataItem());
    }
});
```

Comment: The link to a working example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PytHq/3/, is no longer working...